# Separability of a polynomial by reducing to residue fields

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $A$ be a commutative ring, and $k(p)$ denote the residue field of $A$ at a prime $p$, i.e. $A_p/p A_p$.
Then say a polynomial $f(t) \in A[t]$ is *separable* if $(f,f')=1$.

In Milne's text on Étale Cohomology, Example 3.4, pg. 22, it is claimed that $(f,f')=1$ iff $(\bar f, \bar f')=1$ for all prime $p$, where $\bar f$ is the image of $f$ in $k(p)[t]$.

I could only see $\Rightarrow$. How does one argue the converse?

Comment: If $(f,f')$ is a nontrivial ideal of $A[t]$, then $(f,f')\cap A$ is a proper ideal of $A$, so contained in some prime $p$ etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer copying the response:

**Lemma** Let $I$ be an ideal  of $A[t]$. Then $I=(1)$ iff $I \cap A=A$.

Suppose $I=(f,f')\not =1$, then $I \cap A$ is a *proper* ideal of $A$ by lemma. So $I\cap A \subseteq p$ for some prime ideal of $A$.

Hence, the image of $I$ in $k(p)[t]$, $\bar{I}=(\bar{f}, \bar{f}')$, has trivial intersection with $k(p)$.